# Reading the default namespace through Roslyn API

Tags: .net, roslyn

Is there a way to read the default namespace setting from the IProject interface or any other Roslyn interface? I know that I can parse the project's file but I think this should be possible using Roslyn API but I cannot find how to do that. Thanks in advance for information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Roslyn does not expose a way to do that at the moment, but I agree that it is something we will probably need eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The library Microsoft.Build.Evaluation, which is, I believe, the successor of Roslyn does have this feature, but it is not easy to find.

I use the code below to obtain the default namespace.

My tests have shown that it matches the RootNamespace, stored in the .csproj file.

```
        private string GetDefaultNamespace(Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project p)
    {
        string rtnVal = "UNKNOWN_NAMESPACE";

        foreach (ProjectItemDefinition def in p.ItemDefinitions.Values)
        {
            if (def.ItemType == "ProjectReference")
            {
                foreach(ProjectProperty prop in def.Project.AllEvaluatedProperties){
                    if(prop.Name == "RootNamespace"){
                        rtnVal = prop.EvaluatedValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return rtnVal;
    }
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, however, I don't think this is the successor of Roslyn. Its the other way round... This led to: `project.AllEvaluatedProperties.FirstOrDefault(aep => aep.Name == "RootNamespace")?.EvaluatedValue;`