# Roslyn API: DefaultNamespace

Tags: c#, roslyn

How to get DefaultNamespace from C# - project?

Comment: The ticket - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132175/reading-the-default-namespace-through-roslyn-api
has an answer 3 years ago. I cannot add comment to Kevin Pilch-Bisson's answer (I should have reputation). I added answer with my question to the ticket, but guys removed my question. How I can to ask Kevin Pilch-Bisson about progress with default namespace?

Comment: It is still not possible. It is part of [this Roslyn issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3798), which is scheduled for version 1.2.